# I'm getting a discord.py error saying AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

Tags: python, string, discord, discord.py, attributeerror

```
async def open_account(user):

    users = await get_bank_data()

    if (user.id) in users:
        return False
    else:
        users[str(user.id)] = {}
        users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] = 1000
        users[str(user.id)]["bank"] = 0

    with open("mainbank.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(users,f)
    return True
```

the full error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 902, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 864, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Comment: Which line is raising this error? What does `get_bank_data` do?

Comment: users[str(user.id)] = {}
        users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] = 1000
        users[str(user.id)]["bank"] = 0

these ones and watch this for bank data
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HPaadO_sRD4&t=129s

Comment: Why would that raise this error? What is `users`? It looks like it should behave like a `dict`, which wouldn't raise this kind of exception

Comment: Can you include the *exact* code needed to raise this error? I'm not sure that the stacktrace provided is complete, and the code isn't complete, either. Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @C.Nivs https://repl.it/@xXKarmaYTxX/MyHabitat#main.py

Comment: @Dominik I used https://repl.it as my text editor so the bot can be online 24/7 but how do you use os.chdir in there?

Comment: @Radif This has nothing to do with your actual question. Please open another question for that.I also do not see pings if you do not comment under my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just from your code snippet and the video I also watched I recognized the following mistakes:

```py
if (user.id) in users:
```

This has to be a `str` as well, so change it to `if str(user.id) in users:`

Also your `else:` argument is somehow wrong. You set `1000` as the `"wallet"` amount but it has to be `0`:

```py
    else:
        users[str(user.id)] = {}
        users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] = 0
        users[str(user.id)]["bank"] = 0
```

If it still throws errors something else in your code must be wrong.